# can anyone tell me what is wrong with my prolog code?

Tags: list, prolog

Basically, I want to convert two lists each into a number then add the resulting numbers and output a list representing the digits. Like add([2,2,2,2],[3,3,3],X) would be X =[2,5,5,5]. Internally, [2,2,2,2] and [3,3,3] are converted to 2222 and 333, added to get 2555.  Here is my code and its not working.

```
addlistnum([],[],X).
addlistnum([B|C],[D|E],X) :-
   X is Y + F,
   digits([B|C],Y),
   digits([D|E],F).

digits(Num1,List) :-
   digits(0, List,Num1).

digits(Num1, [], Num1).
digits(N, [B|As],Num1) :-
   N1 is N * 10 + B,
   digits(N1, As,Num1).
```

I'm getting the following error:
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated 
 when I called the addlistnum() passing two lists and a variable. How may fix my code to achieve the desired result?

Comment: move the `X is Y+F` to the end of the clause - or use `library(clpfd)`!

Comment: Actually, it is difficult to define your problem as a relation, should leading zeroes be accepted: Each open argument would permit either zero or infinitely many solutions.

Comment: That error message means, specifically, that there are variables in the expression on the right hand side of your `is` expression, so it can't be evaluated. `is/2` requires that the expression be completely ground so that it can be computed to a value to unify with the term (variable or number) on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't recommend this approach, because you loss the possibility of handle any length numbers. You can try instead:

```
add(A,B,R) :-
  reverse(A,AR),
  reverse(B,BR),
  addl( AR, BR, 0, RR ),
  reverse( R, RR ).

addl( [], [], 0, [] ).
addl( [], [], 1, [1] ).

addl( [H|Q], [], C, R ) :- addl( [H|Q], [0], C, R ).
addl( [], [H|Q], C, R ) :- addl( [H|Q], [0], C, R ).

addl( [AH|AQ], [BH|BQ], C, [RH|RQ] ) :-
  RH is (AH+BH+C) rem 10,
  C2 is (AH+BH+C) div 10,
  addl( AQ, BQ, C2, RQ ).
```

Comment: Can you give an example of such a number, where your approach is more general?

Comment: @false: just compare results in any prolog implementation such as "current_prolog_flag(bounded,true)."

Comment: OK, so you mean GNU and XSB. (I think these are the only ones left. All others (IF, SWI, YAP, B, SICStus, Ciao, Prolog IV) have `bounded` set to `false`

Comment: @false: more interesting ¿which algorithm is faster?

Comment: Before speed, there is the concern for termination. If one would represent numbers in reversed form, something like `reversednumberadd([0|_],[1|_],[2|_])` could fail!